# Is there a way to pass functionality over once a script is loaded in another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a script that calls another script using the `exec(open(---))` stuff seen below. That script then has check buttons that get selected, and then when the "Run" button is used, the selection prints out information to the console window. When i run said script independently, it works perfectly. I can select the buttons and stuff prints. However, when I call the window through another script, all functionality ceases to work. So something isn't getting passed over, and I need to fix that.

I'm using tkinter to do all this in python 3. I can't share a majority of the code for certain reasons.

The first half of this code is the button definition, the second half, starting at hzeprocess(): is the checkboxes from the called script file.

```
def HZEcall():
    exec(open("HZETRAN.py").read())
    hzeopener= Button(self,text="Click to Open HZETRAN Window",command=HZEcall).place(x=15,y=240) 

    Var1 = IntVar()
    Var2 = IntVar()
    Var3 = IntVar()
    Check1 = Checkbutton(self, text="INTERPOLATION",variable= Var1,
                         font='Helvetica10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=60)
    Check2 = Checkbutton(self, text="RAY BY RAY", variable= Var2, 
                         font='Helvetica 10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=95)
    Check3 = Checkbutton(self, text="MCNP", variable= Var3,
                         font='Helvetica 10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=130)

    def hzeprocess():  
        Int = Var1.get()
        Ray = Var2.get()
        MCNPchk = Var3.get()

        if Int == 1:
            print('Interpolation is Selected')
        if Ray == 1:
            print('Ray by Ray is Selected')
        if MCNPchk == 1:
            print('MCNP is Selected')
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In general, it's a pretty bad idea to use `exec`. Instead, perhaps reformat that code to work like a module, and then `import` it to use its functionality!

Comment: agree with @Charles, you should be calling HZETRAN.py as a module.

Comment: @Charles How would you recommend I reformat as a Module instead of a script?

Comment: @Rowdy Davis, that’s tricky to answer without seeing the code to HZETRAN.py. But essentially, everything in that file should live in classes or functions, with essentially nothing in the `if __name__ == ‘__main__’`. Then, in this file, you can call `from  HZETRAN import my_function, my_class`, and then use those functions as if they had been defined in this same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having code having HZEcall and HZETRAN.py in the same directory so this will work while calling this standalone.

But when you will be calling HZEcall function from another script which is not in same directory this will not work as you are calling exec on HZETRAN.py without path, so it will always look for script in current directory of the calling script.

I suggest you do something line below. also read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) to get details for python modules.

```
import HZETRAN
def HZEcall():
    HZETRAN.function_name() # call functionality of HZETRAN
    hzeopener= Button(self,text="Click to Open HZETRAN Window",command=HZEcall).place(x=15,y=240) 

    Var1 = IntVar()
    Var2 = IntVar()
    Var3 = IntVar()
    Check1 = Checkbutton(self, text="INTERPOLATION",variable= Var1,
                         font='Helvetica10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=60)
    Check2 = Checkbutton(self, text="RAY BY RAY", variable= Var2, 
                         font='Helvetica 10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=95)
    Check3 = Checkbutton(self, text="MCNP", variable= Var3,
                         font='Helvetica 10',relief=RAISED).place(x=15, y=130)

    def hzeprocess():  
        Int = Var1.get()
        Ray = Var2.get()
        MCNPchk = Var3.get()

        if Int == 1:
            print('Interpolation is Selected')
        if Ray == 1:
            print('Ray by Ray is Selected')
        if MCNPchk == 1:
            print('MCNP is Selected')
```